# Assembly checking data and moving new data gives error

Tags: assembly, cheat-engine

Hi guys i have very simple problem due to my lack of knowledge I'm facing problem each code I found online its giving errors (can't tell error type because its crashing app)

The task is so simple we have three rows of cod below

```
mov ecx,[rdx]
mov [rax],ecx
ret
```

So basically it gets value from rdx pointer and stores it at ecx and then it pushes that data into rax address!

the problem here is I want to come in middle and check if ecx is is between 6 & 4 only
then replace ecx with 2 and after that push ecx to rax all I tried was fail even I tried putting values into ecx without even checking that also made app crashed what is problem do you guys know any simple solution for this problem ?

- Check if ecx is between 6 & 4
- If Yes -> make ecx 2
- If No -> Continue with code

**We know that ecx is always a integer**

Comment: Are you sure about the `rax` and `rdx` addresses and where they point to? Do they point to a memory region with sufficient permissions?

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: im sure i have access to that memory using cheat-engine its always storing int